# Project not found: 'my-app@dev'

Tags: graphql, graphcool, prisma, prisma-graphql

I am following 
https://www.graph.cool/docs/1.0/quickstart/backend/typescript/typescript-rohd6ipoo4 for graphcool and I an getting the error

```
{
 "errors": [
  {
  "code": 3016,
  "requestId": "api:api:cjc7gf91e002v0180uq2hqace",
  "message": "Project not found: 'my-app@dev'"
}]}
```

for query and mutation. I am new to graphcool so don't have any idea why this is happening. I am following the step provided in the above link.

GraphqlServer:

```
const server = new GraphQLServer({
typeDefs: './src/schema.graphql',
resolvers,
context: req => ({
  ...req,
  db: new Graphcool({
  endpoint: 'http://localhost:60000/my-app/dev',
  secret: 'mysecret123',
    }),
  }),
})

$ graphcool info
Service Name: my-app

dev (cluster: `local`)

HTTP:       http://localhost:60000/my-app/dev
Websocket:  ws://localhost:60000/my-app/dev
```

Comment: Could you show us how you've declared your `GraphQLServer`?

Comment: @Sina please checkout the code.

Comment: Alright, what do you see when commanding `graphcool info`? Side note, these [commands](https://www.graph.cool/docs/reference/graphcool-cli/commands-aiteerae6l/#graphcool-framework-info) could be helpful to figure out what's going wrong.